# Pasar variables de JS a un archivo PHP sin suceso

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un script autocomplete de googleapis donde obtengo los valores correctos de latitud y longitud para el lugar cuyo nombre se ingresó. El problema es que cuando intento pasar estos valores al archivo PHP donde trabajaré con ellos (mi archivo a.php) no sucede nada, probablemente porque en mi ignorancia en JS, debo tener algo mal en el código. He intentado usar código y soluciones que vienen con otras preguntas similares aquí en stackoverflow, pero no puedo encontrar nada que se ajuste a mi caso y mi ignorancia en JS tampoco ayuda. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar un poco? Muchas gracias.

El script JS:

```
    <h1>Predición Meteorológica para su ciudad</h1>
    <input id="searchMapInput" class="mapControls" type="text" placeholder="- 
    Nombre de la ciudad -">
   <ul id="geoData">
   <li>Ciudad: <span id="location-snap"></span></li>
   <li>Latitud: <span id="lat-span"></span></li>
   <li>Longitud: <span id="lon-span"></span></li>
   </ul>

   <script>
   function initMap() {
   var input = document.getElementById('searchMapInput');

   var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

   autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
   var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
   document.getElementById('location-snap').innerHTML = place.formatted_address;
   document.getElementById('lat-span').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lat();
   document.getElementById('lon-span').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lng();
   });
  }

  window.location='a.php?lat='+place.geometry.location.lat+'&long='+place.geometry.location.lng;

  </script>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API_KEY]&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer>
  </script>
```

Y esta es la parte de PHP (un archivo a.php donde recibo las variables transferidas del JS). El problema es que en este archivo lo que obtengo con echo $latitud es tan solo "Latitud: function (){return a}" y con echo $longitud es "Longitud: function (){return b}"

```
  <?php
  $latitud = (isset($_GET['lat']))?$_GET['lat']:'';
  $longitud = (isset($_GET['long']))?$_GET['long']:'';
  echo "Latitud:".$latitud."</br>";
  echo "longitud:".$longitud;
  ?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! java no es lo mismo que javascript, eso es muy importante...

Comment: @gbianchi Muchas gracias y de pronto voy a seguir esas instruciones.

Answer (score 0):

Es que window.location solo devuelve un objeto... Para hacer que te redireccione tienes que usar la propiedad assign de esta forma:

```
window.location.assign('url');
```

Comment: Te dejo este enlace para más info:    https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=859:javascript-redireccionar-y-recargar-webs-windowlocation-href-hostname-assign-reload-replace-cu01171e&catid=78&Itemid=206

Comment: @Vítor Hugo Tirado Muchas gracias por ayudarme y por la documentación que me permitió comprender la jerarquía de JavaScript y el propósito de window.location.assign que intenté usar pero todo sigue igual. Al pasar, la url es "https://misitio.com/a.php?lat=function%20(){return%20a}&long=function%20(){return%20b}" y los "echos" que obtengo en php son "Latitud: function () {return a}" y "Longitud: function () {return b} en lugar de obtener los valores de latitud y longitudinal. ¿Habrá alguna solución que me permita obtener los valores numéricos de $latitud y $longitud? Muchas gracias.

Comment: La propiedad `window.location.assing()` funciona correctamente... al ver tu *URL*, al parecer el problema esta en como obtienes las variables *lat* y *long*, que en vez de retornar un valor te retorna toda la función... Esas funciones no las veo en tu código de ejemplo, seria bueno ver esas funciones y también  como asignas los valores a *lat* y *long*

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora entendi cual es el problema y voy a seguir sus recomendaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Una pequeña modificación en el script es la solución:

```
  <script>
  function initMap(){
  var searchInput = 'searchMapInput';

 var autocomplete;
 autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById(searchInput)), {
 types: ['geocode']
 });

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
var near_place = autocomplete.getPlace();
var address = near_place.formatted_address;
var latitude = near_place.geometry.location.lat();
var longitude = near_place.geometry.location.lng();

document.getElementById('location-snap').innerHTML = address;
document.getElementById('lat-span').innerHTML = latitude;
document.getElementById('lon-span').innerHTML = longitude;

window.location.href='a.php?adress='+address+'&lat='+latitude+'&long='+longitude;
});
}
</script>
```